# Proof that every noninvertiable multivector has an idempotent factor.

Tags: geometric-algebras

> Prove that every multivector which does not have an inverse has an idempotent for a factor.
>
> Define an idempotent as a multivector $A$ with the property that $A^2=A$ and $A \neq 1$.

I can show it for specific cases, such as, $B = \beta + \mathbf b$, $\beta$ a scalar and $\mathbf b$ a vector, and $C = \langle C \rangle_0 + \langle C \rangle_1 + \langle C \rangle_2$.  But I can't figure out how to show it in the general case.

Comment: You mean a factor with respect to the geometric product, right?

Comment: That's what I meant.  Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A geometric algebra over a nonsingular finite dimensional $F$-vector space is a semisimple ring, so it is [von Neumann regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_regular_ring). As such, for every $a$ in the ring, there exists $x$ such that $axa=a$.

From this you can compute that $ax$ is an idempotent, and clearly it's a factor of $a$. If $ax=1$, then since the ring is Artinian it is also true that $xa=1$, and $a$ would be a unit. So if $a$ is not a unit, $ax\neq 1$.

Comment: Ah.  I guess my 1 semester of abstract algebra isn't enough for this question because I've never heard of semisimple rings (and it doesn't seem to even be in Artin's book which I have right here).  So I'll just have to trust that this is correct and I'll accept it.

Comment: @BobDylan Which book are you looking at? There is more than one Artin, and there is more than one book by both Artins.

Comment: The book I used in my abstract algebra class was *Algebra* by Michael Artin. ----- I got this question from *New Foundations for Classical Mechanics* by Hestenes.  He doesn't actually ask the reader to prove this, he just states it as a fact.  So I thought I'd take a crack at it.

Comment: @BobDylan Thanks for letting me know. That's the fastest way I know to prove this: through a little abstract algebra. The basics of semisimple rings are worth picking up, if you have the time :)